# radio button change only after confirm() returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I've got a set of radio buttons in my html site. When the users changes the selection I show a dialog via the confirm('') function. I just want to change the selection if the user confirms the change - otherwise just cancel the event. My problem now is that I only got an event AFTER the value has been changes and the change is already done. How can i prevent this behaviour?

Comment: onCancel button click you can put reset using javascript, that may help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('.rdio').click(function(){
 var cnfrm = confirm('Are you sure?');
 if(cnfrm != true)
{
 return false;
}

})​
```

**live demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/cTzVg/

Comment: Nice and simple, especially since you can replace the entire thing with a one liner `return confirm('Sure?');` but the problem is that it doesn't work in IE. Pressing cancel doesn't restore the previous selection. So saving the previous selection in a page scoped variable looks unavoidable.

Comment: This helped me! NOTE: you don't have to check `cnfrm != true` as confirm returns boolean value `true` on "OK" and `false` on "Cancel", all you have to do is rearrange your `if - else`. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for giving solution but this doesn't work in IE. On Cancel button IE deselects all radio buttons. Please provide any work around to work in IE.

Comment: needed to fetch the current_radio and add `current_radio.checked= false` before `return false` in a case where no radio button is checked to start with (like the jsfiddle linked above). Otherwise the radio button gets checked even if confirm returned false. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6b46y4sm/1/

Answer (score 4):

This isn't easy because there is no consistency across browsers in which event is appropriate to do what you need doing. However you say from your tags you're using jQuery, so here's a solution using state tracking to revert depending on your function return:

```
var currentradio= $("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked")[0];
$("input[name='pick_up_point']").change(function(event) {
    var newradio= $("input[name='pick_up_point']:checked")[0];

    if (newradio===currentradio)
        return;
    if (confirm('Your question here')) {
        currentradio= newradio;
    } else {
        currentradio.checked= true;
    }
});
```